# Why do I keep getting this error: "Element type is invalid" when I try using ReactComponent to import svg files

Tags: reactjs, svg

`import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from "../../assets/icons/12x12/arrow-down-12.svg"`

and when I return , I keep getting this error:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

I've tried inserting the  component into another one, but still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not working?

EDIT:
My webpack config contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

Comment: Are you using appropriate loaders for handling svg?

Comment: I don't know. What do I need to use?

Comment: Share your webpack config. Will check if the proper loaders are present. Check this article for details: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-load-svg-with-react-and-webpack

Comment: @NaserMohdBaig I just did. Check it out.